# How to get text from inside a <span class="className">TEXT I WANT</span> in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

How to get the text as per the Title which amounts to `21,427` as per the screenshot below.

I tried this and it did not work:

```
rating_count = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'rating_count'})
print rating_count
```

[image]

This is the output

[image]

Comment: FWIW, people here prefer the text of the error itself to an screenshot of the stack trace. :)

Comment: Got it, will post error in future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do exactly what you are looking for.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

data='<span class="rating-count">TEXT I WANT</span>'
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
t=soup.find('span',{'class':'rating-count'})
print t.text
```

### EDITED:

According the code you have provided. It looks like that as there is not a header defined, google doesn't send the information that you are looking for. Consequently, BeautifulSoup could't find the span because it didn't exist actually. Try this, it works for me:

```
pkg = "com.mavdev.focusoutfacebook"
url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + pkg
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
data = opener.open(url).read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(data)

t=soup.find('span',{'class':'rating-count'})
print t.text
```

Result:

```
>>> 
1,397
```

Comment: Does it matter if this span is inside another span? I'm still having the same issue: http://pastebin.com/FYKLANJK

Comment: It works in the same way,it doesn't matter whether or not the span is nested. I checked your code and the problem you are facing is about urllib2 and headers and not BeautifulSoup as such. I edited my previous post. Hopefully, it also works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you've incorrectly typed what the span's class is.  If you look closely at the image you posted, it says that the span's class is **rating-count**, whereas you've typed **rating_count** into BeautifulSoup.  It therefore looks for **rating_count**, doesn't find it, and returns `NoneType`.

```
rating_count = soup.find("span",{'class':'rating-count'}).text
print rating_count
```

Comment: If you notice the image he posted, he is trying to do the same by doing `appDict['rating_count'] = rating_count.text`. Since `rating_count` is a NoneType (by Exception he gets), it will fail.

Comment: He's got the class typed incorrectly, the first line of my edited post fixes it.  He's getting NoneType because 'rating_count' **isn't** the span class.  It's rating-count

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that.

Comment: @n1c9 Still not working for me, here's my complete code: http://pastebin.com/FYKLANJK

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get content from multiple containers in a page? Can you do a count of span class: rating-count in the DOM and see whether there are other elements that use same class name. It might be because some other elements with same class name is EMPTY. If so, you can do an IF-ELSE to assign 'null' into your attribute.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.